# Android Studio refactor app icons

Tags: android, icons

Need some help.
I made a refactor from my first app (the one with the factory icon) to a new one (wool icon).
Everything works fine except the icons!
Some of them are updated but others not. In the status bar and in the system, icons are the old ones (factory icons).
After looking, i don't have any old image files in the project folder.

Could anyone find the solution for this?

[image: Android Studio Image Asset]

[image: Installing APP (Correct icon)]

[image: Correct icon in the menu]

[image: First icon problem, On installed APPs (wrong icon, old one)]

[image: Managed APPs, wrong Icon]

[image: Status bar, wrong icon]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're naming the new icon `ic_icone`. However, the launcher icon needs to be named `ic_launcher` if you don't want to edit the manifest. If you want to call it `ic_icone`, you have to edit your manifest and replace the value in `android:icon` to target `ic_icone` instead of `ic_launcher`.

**TL;DR:** change the name to `ic_launcher`, or change the value of `android:icon` in the manifest

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename them the same as your original icons (and they have to be placed on the same folder (right click > show in explorer), remember that there are two sets of icons, regular and rounded (Just in case).

It could also be the case that they already replaced but they aren't loading for you (older machine), so if they don't load make sure to go to File > Invalidate Cache & Restart

Answer (score 0):

Thks for your answers Darkly and Zoe!
Try your tips and the problem still happens.

After another check i found that even made the refactor there were some variables that dont change like was supposed.

For example:
In build.gradle (Module:app)

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27 -------------> Old one was 26

defaultConfig {

    applicationId "rtomas.wool" -----------> This fill don't change with refactor. I need to change it manually to the new one.

    minSdkVersion 22

    targetSdkVersion 27 -------------> Old one was 26

    versionCode 1
    versionName "2.2"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'-------------> Old one was 26

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'-------------> Old one was 26

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.esri.arcgisruntime:arcgis-android:100.2.1'

implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'-------------> Old one was 26

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

}

After your tips, change the "applicationId" name, updating the "targetSdkVersion" and all the dependencies the problem were solved!

For the note, i was testing my app on a 7.0 android version.

Many thks! :)